# vim ignoring .vimrc syntax highlighting

Tags: macos, command-line, catalina, vi

I had a `~/.vimrc` with some basic syntax highlighting that was working fine until I upgraded to Catalina. Running `vim -V` I see it loads my vimrc but it totally ignores anything in it. If I run `:so ~/.vimrc` inside vim it also ignores it, but if I run the commands from the vimrc one by one then it accepts them.

How do I get vim to source my vimrc again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My syntax rules were being overwritten by later files in the load order, for some reason this happens now when it didn't before. The solution was to copy my `.vimrc` into `~/.vim/after/syntax/syncolor.vim` (the filename matters too apparently)